# Angular services with browserfy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've using the angular fullstack generator for a long time and I recently updated it and noticed it no longer uses bower and that it uses require to get the modules in the client. My issue is that I can't understand how this works at all when I try to declare a service.

if I run, for example, `yo angular-fullstack:service example` it creates a `example.service.js` in the `client/app/example` path with the following code:

```
'use strict';
const angular = require('angular');

/*@ngInject*/
export function exampleService() {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
}

export default angular.module('sisaApp.example', [])
  .service('example', exampleService)
  .name;
```

Let's say that I want to use `$http` here. Do I pass it as a parameter to the function?

Apart from that, how do I go about injecting this service into a controller?
If I run `yo angular-fullstack:route myroute` and it generates th following controller file:

```
'use strict';
const angular = require('angular');

const uiRouter = require('angular-ui-router');

import routes from './myroute.routes';

export class MyrouteComponent {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor() {
    this.message = 'Hello';
  }
}

export default angular.module('sisaApp.myroute', [uiRouter])
  .config(routes)
  .component('myroute', {
    template: require('./myroute.html'),
    controller: MyrouteComponent,
    controllerAs: 'myrouteCtrl'
  })
  .name;
```

Doing it the old was by passing it as a parameter into the constructor doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [ngInject](https://github.com/bholloway/browserify-nginject) should handle your dependencies reading parameter names and create `$inject` array. Do you have any errors in console? And what do you mean by "old way"?

Comment: The old way was using bower and whenever I would create a service I would just pass the name of the service as a parameter to the constructor of the controller. If I try to do it this way I get an Unknown provider error.